# How to completely delete file on MediaFire

Tags: mediafire

Is there a way to delete file directly, bypassing Trash folder, using Mediafire API? When I try to delete file, I call the method http://www.mediafire.com/api/file/delete.php, which moves file in the Trash. It seems this folder can be purged only through Browser. Does API offer a way to clean the Trash folder?

Comment: It's Mediafire's API. You should probably ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always look for their documentation, as this answer was [extracted from there](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/core_api/unversioned/file.php#purge):

## Purge

Description : **Permanently delete a user's file.**

Required Parameters:

> session_token : A type 1 or type 2 session token. (Type 2 will require a call signature).
>       quick_key : The quickkey, or a list of quickkeys separated by commas, that identify the files to be purged. The maximum number of quickkeys allowed is 500.

Optional Parameters:

> signature : This is the call signature that is required to authenticate a type 2 session token transaction.
>   response_format : 'xml' or 'json' (default 'xml')